# Pandas: Find maximum value in row and retrieve it's column position

Tags: pandas, loops, max

Morning!

I want to find the maximum value for each row of my dataset.

Example:

| ID | Age | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | NaN | 6 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 25 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 30 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 5 | NaN | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 27 | 1 | 8 | 4 |

Then, for ID #2 knowing that the max value from the subset [Col_A; Col_B; Col_C] is 9 from Col_C I want to input the missing value as the mean Age of the ID's which also had the max value in Col_C.

In this case, the Age of ID #2 will be the average from Age ID#3 and ID#4 which will be 28.

Comment: what about the Age of ```ID = 5``` where there's no other ID with max being Col_A?

Comment: I would say to try to find the second max value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary column which shows which is the max column for each ID using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and perform it column-wise, `(axis=1)`, using only the `Col_` columns.

Then impute the missing Age with a grouped average on the new column, using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)  and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['max_col'] = df.filter(like='Col_').idxmax(axis=1)
df['Age_filled'] = round(df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('max_col')['Age'].transform('mean')))
```

Prints:

```
  ID   Age  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C max_col
0   1  20.0      1      5      3   Col_B
1   2  28.0      6      8      9   Col_C
2   3  25.0      5      6      7   Col_C
3   4  30.0      3      4      6   Col_C
4   5   NaN      6      2      1   Col_A
5   6  27.0      1      8      4   Col_B
```

For `ID = 5`, there is no other ID which has the maximum value in Col_A. So for such occasions, it is still left `np.nan`